# Download file with international characters in file name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application I'm uploading a file which has Swedish characters in file name. It works fine.
But when I try to download it, I get an error: "An invalid character was found in the mail header" ..Could you help regarding this
Please see my code

```
public ActionResult Download(Guid id)
{
   var attachment = AttachmentService.GetAttachmentById(id);
   var cd = new ContentDisposition
                {
                  FileName = Utility.GetCleanedFileName(((FileAttachment)attachment).FileName),
                  Inline = false,
                };

   var file = File("\\App_Data" +((FileAttachment)attachment).FilePath, "Application");

   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.Clear();
   Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

   var filePath = "\\App_Data" + ((FileAttachment) attachment).FilePath;

   Response.WriteFile(filePath);
   Response.End();

   return file;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a filename? Also which browser you are testing?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to encode the filename using `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx